Error occurred when I use nodejs to implement huggingface inference api
Huggingface has provided convinent reference api to implement or test Models.
I tried to implement Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2 in nodejs but fail.
There are three ways provided to implement it(python, javascript and curl).
When I use javascript it works well.
The code is below. I use the example code provided by huggingface.
async function query(data) {
    const response = await fetch(
        "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer hf_xxxxx",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}

query({"inputs": "Can you please let us know more details about your "}).then((response) => {
    document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});

And I use postman to send a POST request and it works as well(I get the response).
But when I tried to do the same thing in nodejs, it fails. The code is below.
async function query(data) {
    const response = await fetch(
        "https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.2",
        {
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer hf_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        }
    );
    const result = await response.json();
    return result;
}

query({"inputs": "Can you please let us know more details about your "}).then((response) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
});

Here is the error:
node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457
    Error.captureStackTrace(err, this);
          ^

TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async query (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX\xxx.js:2:19) {
  cause: ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
      at onConnectTimeout (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8422:28)
      at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8380:50
      at Immediate._onImmediate (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:8409:37)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
    code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
  }
}

Node.js v18.16.1

I have tested that fetch works well in Node.js v18.16.1. I don't know why I get a timeout error.
I have tried different libs to send POST request, like http, https, axios and node-fetch. None of them works.

The code you posted is working as expected in node.js
Make sure to check the internet connection

I am very confused about this. Since my javascript version and postman can work well, I think that there should not be any internet problem. If there is internet problem, js and postman will not work. However, the nodejs can't work on my computer. So is there any other explanations about this problem? Thank you so much. This bug has bothered me a lot.

I tried on node.js v20 it worked without any error. I know the fetch failed error is confusing since it doesn't tell a lot about the problem

I have found something strange. I use fiddler to grab the datapack sent by application. When I use javascript and postman to do the POST request, I can get the datapack in fiddler. But when I use nodejs to do the same thing, I see nothing in the fiddler. So maybe nodejs haven't sent anything out. In this situation, how to repair it?

OK, I will update the nodejs and try again if there is still bug.
